# Can I delete Recovery partition?

Tags: 20.10, disk-management

I have installed Ubuntu just 3 hours ago and have alloted two other partitions that is swap area and ext 4. I am able to find the partitions but there has been created another partition named as Disk 0 partition 6 and alongside there is written Healthy(Recovery Partition) Can I delete that partition or if I do not delete it will occupy more space in the disk ? Here is a image of that partition the highlighted one is the partition please tell can I delete it or is there any harm if it is on my Disk ?[image]

Comment: Are you saying that partition 6 never existed and ubuntu automatically created it? unlikely. As far as I know it's Windows' partition. You may keep it. It's half a GB doesn't make much of space and it will not increase as well.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer